# Parsing a keystroke record using input_event structure return strange key codes

Tags: c, linux, xlib, keylogger

Given:

- A machine running Debian 10 and using the french keyboard mapping.
- A dump of keystrokes correspoding to "azerty" obtained using:

```
sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd > test_keylogger_azerty
```

- The following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_keysyms.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int fd, col;
    xcb_connection_t *connection;
    xcb_key_symbols_t *symbols;
    struct input_event ev;
    if (ac != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <dump file> <symbol table index>\n", av[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    symbols = xcb_key_symbols_alloc(connection);
    col = atoi(av[2]);

    fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
    while (read(fd, (void *) &ev, sizeof(ev))) {
            if (ev.type == EV_KEY && ev.value == 1)
                printf("type: %x code: %x  value: %2x => %s\n", 
                    ev.type, ev.code, ev.value,
                    XKeysymToString(xcb_key_symbols_get_keysym(symbols, ev.code, col)));
    }
    printf("\n");
    close(fd);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

A test run with `xev` tell me that: `a == 24`, `b == 25` [...] `y == 29`.
Nevertheless, when i run my program, the obtained code don't match (and, as a result, the guessed corresponding symbol doesn't match too):

```
$ ./reverse_kl test_keylogger_azerty 0
type: 1 code: 10  value:  1 => egrave
type: 1 code: 11  value:  1 => underscore
type: 1 code: 12  value:  1 => ccedilla
type: 1 code: 13  value:  1 => agrave
type: 1 code: 14  value:  1 => parenright
type: 1 code: 15  value:  1 => equal
type: 1 code: 1c  value:  1 => t
type: 1 code: 1d  value:  1 => y
type: 1 code: 2e  value:  1 => l
```

if i modify my code that way:

```
$ diff reverse_kl.c{.ref,}
33c33
<                     XKeysymToString(xcb_key_symbols_get_keysym(symbols, ev.code , col)));
---
>                     XKeysymToString(xcb_key_symbols_get_keysym(symbols, ev.code + 8 , col)));
```

It works better:

```
$ ./reverse_kl test_keylogger_azerty 0
type: 1 code: 10  value:  1 => a
type: 1 code: 11  value:  1 => z
type: 1 code: 12  value:  1 => e
type: 1 code: 13  value:  1 => r
type: 1 code: 14  value:  1 => t
type: 1 code: 15  value:  1 => y
type: 1 code: 1c  value:  1 => Return
type: 1 code: 1d  value:  1 => Control_L
type: 1 code: 2e  value:  1 => c
```

Also, note that, for key 'a', i have the code `10` and adding `8` still don't give me `24` but it's working...

If anyone could help me understanding this strange behaviour ...

EDIT:
Added an hexadecimal dump of the trace as requested:

```
0000000 66 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 2b 7c 04 00 00 00 00 00
0000020 04 00 04 00 28 00 07 00 66 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000040 2b 7c 04 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00
0000060 66 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 2b 7c 04 00 00 00 00 00
0000100 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000120 a7 01 0e 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 04 00 14 00 07 00
0000140 66 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 a7 01 0e 00 00 00 00 00
0000160 01 00 10 00 01 00 00 00 66 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000200 a7 01 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000220 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 22 11 01 00 00 00 00 00
0000240 04 00 04 00 14 00 07 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000260 22 11 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
0000300 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 22 11 01 00 00 00 00 00
0000320 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000340 fc fe 03 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 04 00 1a 00 07 00
0000360 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 fc fe 03 00 00 00 00 00
0000400 01 00 11 00 01 00 00 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000420 fc fe 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000440 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 ab 31 06 00 00 00 00 00
0000460 04 00 04 00 1a 00 07 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000500 ab 31 06 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 11 00 00 00 00 00
0000520 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 ab 31 06 00 00 00 00 00
0000540 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000560 1d e7 07 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 04 00 08 00 07 00
0000600 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 1d e7 07 00 00 00 00 00
0000620 01 00 12 00 01 00 00 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000640 1d e7 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000660 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 23 58 0a 00 00 00 00 00
0000700 04 00 04 00 08 00 07 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
0000720 23 58 0a 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 12 00 00 00 00 00
0000740 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00 23 58 0a 00 00 00 00 00
0000760 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 67 35 4d 5d 00 00 00 00
```

As a reminder, below is the format of the input_event structure:

```
struct input_event {
struct timeval time;
__u16 type;
__u16 code;
__s32 value;
};
```

And, other reminder, keyboard stroke obey the following rules:

- `type == EV_KEY == 0x01`
- `value` may be `0` for event "key released", `1` for "key pressed" and `2` is for "auto-repeat".

Comment: A (partial) hex dump of `test_keylogger_azerty` might be interesting. (something like `od -tx1 test_keylogger_azerty|head -30`)

Comment: @bodo : done + added some details regarding struct input_event and interesting values in my case.

Comment: I've never done this sort of work on Linux, only Windows, but I suspect the `code` here might be a keyboard scan code, as opposed to a character code.

Comment: The key events from your dump correspond to release ENTER, press Q, release Q, press W, release W, press E, release E, according to https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h (With AZERTY layout, QWE correspond to AZE.) So these values should be OK. Is `ev.code` the correct input for `xcb_key_symbols_get_keysym`? `ev.code` is 16 bits wide and `input-event-codes.h` defines `KEY_*` values >255 while the 2nd argument of `xcb_key_symbols_get_keysym` is `uint8_t`. I didn't find sufficient documentation of this function.

Comment: @bodo same here ... finding documentation regarding  this topic is quite difficult. But i'll dig about variable lenght. Thanks !